# How to remove a route from react navigation stack?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

So in my react-native project i have a Stack.Navigator like this.

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} />
    {authState.isLoggedIn && authState.token !== "" ? (
    <>
        <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={Root} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Detail" component={DetailScreen} />
    </>
    ) : (
    <>
        <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={WelcomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
    </>
    )}
</Stack.Navigator>
```

SignIn Function:

```
const onSignIn = () => {
    dispatch(
        signIn({
            /// ...userData,
            isLoggedIn: true,
        })
    );
};
```

Flow when opening App:

- isLoggedIn = false, Splash -> Welcome (Press Button in Welcome) -> SignIn (Press Login and update isLoggedIn flag to true) -> Splash -> Root

What i expect is that after the user has login from SignIn page, the user doesn't need to see Splash page again. I have read about CommonActions and StackActions but i don't understand how to properly use it.

Note: I'm using redux to handle the authState and even though that i don't manually navigate it, it is already navigate to Splash and Root Page

Have tried this but still does not work

```
const onSignIn = () => {
    navigation.dispatch(
        CommonActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            routes: [{ name: "Splash" }],
        })
    );
    dispatch(
        signIn({
            /// ...userData,
            isLoggedIn: true,
        })
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

this will reset navigation stack to the route you are navigating and every thing else will be cleared so when user press back button there will be no screen to go back to.

```
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

use navigateToScreen method and pass route name you want to navigate to

```
 //---- CLEAR STACK AND REDIRECT USER TO ANOTHER SCREEN ----//
    const navigateToScreen = (name) => {
        navigation.dispatch(
            CommonActions.reset({
                index: 0,
                routes: [{ name },],
            })
        );
    }
```

Comment: when the SignIn function being called, it will update the authState in the redux, so isLoggedIn is true. So in this case i don't need to navigate, it will automatically use the authenticate route (include Root & Detail and exclude the Welcome and SignIn). Also in the react navigation documentation it said that its not good to manually navigate when we have authentication flow in the Stack.Navigator. And i have tried your solution but it does not work

Comment: question updated